# How to disable custom actions buttons on Apple Watch when receiving push notification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, 3dtouch

I am developing an iOS app with 3D Touch push notifications. The notification has a couple of custom actions defined.

When receiving the notification on an Apple Watch, these same custom actions are displayed. However, since:

- I am not yet planning to create a companion Apple Watch app to handle the [long-look interface of the notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/enhancing_your_watchos_app_with_notifications), and
- these custom actions require interaction with the iOS app based on an enhanced preview of the notification when received on an iOS device,

these actions make little sense on the watch.

Is there a way I can disable these actions when receiving a push notification on an Apple Watch?

Thanks in advance!